# Is it possible to know what user write without pressing enter?

Tags: c

I want to check if the user writes something like "car" then I can print "You want to buy it?" or something like that. Is it possible to do that in C?

EDIT: I use Windows. `getch()` is good but it doesnt show what user writes on the screen. I tried to use `putchar()`to show them but I cant delete the character on the screen. How do I fix it, or use `getch()` in my case?

Comment: It should be possible, if I recall my old trials earlier. I'll type a code now, be right back.

Comment: It is operating system specific. What OS do you use? Please **edit your question** to improve it.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Thanks for reminding me. This is the first time I ask a question on StackOverFlow.

Comment: @Phúc I've provided an answer for both operating systems. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the system you may use (not always possible) conio - for dos and windows console, ncurses for linux or other related for your system

ncurses - http://www.cs.ukzn.ac.za/~hughm/os/notes/ncurses.html#input

Comment: Thank for your information

Comment: @Phúc - no prob

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example in Windows, as the other answers suggested this is platform dependant.

What I do here is, I've created a function to append a `char` to a `"string"`. Then I've checked if the keyboard is hit with `_kbhit()`, if it's hit, I've recorded the value into `c` variable. Afterwards with our custom function, appended the `c` variable to `str`, and checked if first 3 characters of our `str` is `"car"` or not.

If it's car, it prints the value you've requested in your question, if user keeps typing, since first 3 characters are now car, it will keep printing the same thing on each key press. You can handle it.

What's the purpose of the `counter`? It allows you to add a new character to `str` each loop by making sure that if statement works as intended.

I hope this answer helps you, in the near future, I'll also provide an example for Linux.

## Windows

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *append_char(char *sz_string, size_t strsize, char c);

int main()
{
    char str[] = "";
    int counter = 1;
    while (1)
    {
        if (_kbhit()) {
            const char c = _getch();
            append_char(str, sizeof str + counter, c);
            if (strncmp(str, "car", 3) == 0)
            {
                printf("Do you want to buy it?\n");
            }
            counter++;
        }
    }
}

char *append_char(char *sz_string, size_t strsize, char c)
{
    size_t len = strlen(sz_string);
    if ((len + 1) < strsize)
    {
        sz_string[len++] = c;
        sz_string[len] = '\0';
        return sz_string;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

## Linux

```
#include <termios.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static struct termios old, new;

void initTermios(int echo)
{
    tcgetattr(0, &old);
    new = old;
    new.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
    if (echo) {
        new.c_lflag |= ECHO;
    }
    else {
        new.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;
    }
    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &new);
}

void resetTermios(void)
{
    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &old);
}

char getch_(int echo)
{
    char ch;
    initTermios(echo);
    ch = getchar();
    resetTermios();
    return ch;
}

char _getch(void)
{
    return getch_(0);
}

char *append_char(char *sz_string, size_t strsize, char c)
{
    size_t len = strlen(sz_string);
    if ((len + 1) < strsize)
    {
        sz_string[len++] = c;
        sz_string[len] = '\0';
        return sz_string;
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    char str[] = "";
    int counter = 1;
    while (1)
    {
        const char c = _getch();
        append_char(str, sizeof str + counter, c);
        if (strncmp(str, "car", 3) == 0)
        {
            printf("Do you want to buy it?\n");
        }
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But I want to print what user write on the screen, can you help me?

Comment: Yes, I'll edit the code to fit in your needs in a few minutes.

Comment: Thank you. I have a question that is how to delete some wrong character. Do I have to write str[len(str)] = '\0' or something like that?

Answer (score -1):

You can try using getch() in a loop.

getch() is a nonstandard function and is present in conio.h header file which is mostly used by MS-DOS compilers like Turbo C. It is not part of the C standard library or ISO C, nor is it defined by POSIX (Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h)
Like above functions, it reads also a single character from keyboard. But it does not use any buffer, so the entered character is immediately returned **without waiting for the enter key**.

[More information](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-getchar-getch-getc-getche/)

Comment: `getch` don't exist on many operating systems, such as POSIX, Linux, MacOSX, Android...

Comment: Thanks. But I have problems to use it (on edit). Can you help me?

Comment: Note: material that is copy+pasted from other websites may be flagged for the attention of the Review Queue, even if you have added an attribution link. It is generally better to answer in your own words if you can.